# change widht sibling css doesnt work html

Tags: html, css

im trying to make a container, u have the code below, in which it have 4 divs, one doesnt change and the other three change the widht depend where u pass the mouse.

In the first div, c52, works fine but the others two doesnt affect the precious divs.
I try to use ~ and + but nothing change.

Do you know what problem I have in my code?

Thanks.

```css
#triangulo{
    float: right;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 0 2vw 1vw 2vw;
    border-color: transparent transparent #F5BC00 transparent;
}
#triespacio{
    height:1vw; 
    width:85vw;
    float:right;
}
#contenedor5{
    float: left;
    width: 90vw;
    height: 95vh;
    color: #FDFDFD;
    background: whitesmoke;
}
#yo{
    float: left;
    width: 10vw;
    
}
#yop{
    border-radius: 50%;
    padding: 5vmin;
}
#c51{
    margin-top: 2vmin;
    float: left;
    width: 24vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background: rgb(60, 80, 130);       
}
#c52{
    margin: 2vmin;
    float: left;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background: #f6c164;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
#c52:hover{
    width: 40vw;
}
#c52:hover ~ #c53 {
    width: 10vw;
}
#c52:hover ~ #c54 {
    width: 10vw;
}
#c53{
    margin: 2vmin;
    float: left;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background: #b5d8ad;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
#c53:hover{
    width: 40vw;
}
#c53:hover ~ #c52  {
    width: 10vw;
}
#c53:hover ~ #c54 {
    width: 10vw;
}
#c54{
    margin: 2vmin;
    float: left;
    width: 20vw;
    height: 90vh;
    background: #bcd6de;
    transition: width 1s ease-in-out, left 1.5s ease-in-out;
}
#c54:hover{
    width: 40vw;
}
#c54:hover ~ #c52 {
    width: 10vw;
}
#c54:hover ~ #c53 {
    width: 10vw;
}
```

```html
<div id="contenedor5">
        <a href="main.html"><div id="triangulo"></div></a>
        <div id="triespacio"></div>  
            <div id="c51">
                <div id="yo">
                    <img id="yop" src="yo.jpg" alt="foto" style="width:100%">
                </div>
            </div>  
            <div id="c52">
                soy c52
            </div> 
            <div id="c53">
                soy c53
            </div>  
            <div id="c54">
                soy c54
            </div>  
    </div>
```

Comment: you have no problem, you simply want to achieve something that cannot be done with CSS

Comment: `one doesnt change and the other three change the widht` which one doesn't changed?? can you elaborate little more what you want to achieve?

Comment: Thanks Temani, using javascript then?

Comment: Suresh if u see the code when i press the c52 the other two change the size to be smaller meanwhile c52 make it bigger.    In the other two doesnt happend that, the c53 change the c54 widht but not the c52 and c54 doesnt change nothing.

Comment: yes JS or check the above question you may find some trick or workaround

Comment: Hi, I have had the same problem. JS is the better solution. The workarounds might be problematic after some time.